# Laravel Queue worker dies after completing task

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have some troubles with laravel queue system.
I use the following command to run my jobs:

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=0 --queue=export > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!;
```

Unfortunately, after completing each task this process kills itself. Laravel logs are clear, failed_jobs table is clear.

Thank you!

UPD:

I tried running job handler not in background

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=0 --queue=export
```

The process finished after first job has been completed. No errors, just the process has finished. Job was completed successfully, but process died.

Laravel version is 8.76.2

I think the problem is in job class, because similar job handler on this site is working properly.

Comment: What version o Laravel you're using?

Comment: Of course there aren't errors, you are hiding them. Get rid of `> /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!; ` and then you'll see logs in the terminal. Looks like you're running this manually? I assume that's just for testing.

Comment: @miken32 I think even with `/dev/null` the Laravel pipeline would log errors in its log files, since that operator applies to the output of the command, it doesnt determine what happens *inside* the php command. Yes it hides errors from the terminal window but that is not what is referred to here.

Comment: @sajjadrezaee the larval version is 8.76.2
Moreover, answering miken32 question - I tried to run the queue not in background (php artisan queue:work --timeout=0 --queue=export
The process died after first job has been completed.

Comment: @Flame yes the Laravel log would be unaffected but hiding the terminal output could hide information.

Comment: Try without the timeout parameter and see what happens? Default is 60 seconds.

Comment: @miken32 I have already tried, nothing changed. Recently I've noticed, that similar job handler processes jobs normally. I tried to put return at the start of the job function - and magic, after finishing the task job handler didn't die. I will give more  precise description and the reason of this behaviour as soon as I find it. Thanks everybody!

Comment: If you suspect the job class is a problem, please add it to your question.

Comment: @miken32 Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3):

Solved! The problem was in **memory limit**. After completing each task laravel queue worker checks if memory limit was exceed. If so - it just kills process - you can see it in `Illuminate\Queue\Worker::daemon` (stopIfNecessary function).

Solution is **providing --memory flag** when running job handler. The result code will be:

```
php artisan queue:work --memory=512 --timeout=0 --queue=export
```

Thanks everybody!